# Js if statement with HTML input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

cant see what im doing wrong here. Im trying to get javascript to right to console when "hi" is typed into the input field.

```
    const username = document.getElementById('item');
let messages = []

if(username == "hi"){
  console.log("hello")
}
```

^that was my js

```
    <div>
    <label>Search database</label>
    <input type="text" id="item" autofocus></input>

  </div>
```

^html

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a `listener` on the input as follows:

```js
document.getElementById('item').addEventListener("input",function(){
     if(this.value == "hi"){
          console.log("hello")
     }  
});
```

```html
<div>
    <label>Search database</label>
    <input type="text" id="item" autofocus/>
</div>
```

Comment: weird, i get this error in console. "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"

Comment: @Squeecy are you placing the ``script`` at the bottom of the ``body``?

Comment: its in its own .js document linked to the html.

Comment: place it in the bottom or wrap your code with ``document.onload = function(){...``